# how to fix this error Class 'App\link' not found

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

[image]
hallo i got some error in my website after publish. my website didnt get error when i use in localhost, but i got an error when i publish into a hosting. the error called "Class 'App\link' not found". the code is nothing different with my code in my localhost. how can i fix that?
here some code on public_html/app/Http/Controllers/Backend/LinkController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\link;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Website;

class LinkController extends BackendController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $website = Website::get();
        $link = Link::get();
        return view("backend.link.index", compact('link', 'website'));
    }
```

and /public_html/app/Link.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Link extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['judul', 'url', 'jenis_id', 'user_id'];
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function dateFormatted($showTimes = false)
    {
        $format = "d/m/Y";
        if ($showTimes) $format . "H:i:s";
        return $this->created_at->format($format); 
    }

}
```

please help

Comment: typo: `use App\link` != `use App\Link`...

Comment: @jibsteroos why it doesnt effect in localhost?

Comment: because some systems actually have filesystems that are case sensitive (you should just always assume that case matters then you won't have any issue)

Answer (score 0):

change "link" the first letter user an uppercase
change this use App\link;

into this use App\Link;

Answer (score 0):

its just a typing mistake, change link

```
use App\link;
```

into this

```
use App\Link;
```